# COM wrapper with C++/CLI and C# "as" operator

Tags: c#, com, c++-cli

I'm writing a COM wrapper in C++/CLI and struggling with how to approach a problem.

From C# side, I'll call a code like this:

```
var item = myWrappedObj.getSomeItem() as AnotherItem;
```

C++/CLI managed side holds a pointer to the unmanaged object:

```
public ref class MyWrapped {
    NativeType* unManagedEl;
public:
    Object^ getSomeItem() { return unManagedEl->getSomeItem(); }
    ...
};
```

and C++/CLI unmanaged side does the job and, let's say returns an IUnknown* wrapped in an UnknownBase native class

```
public class UnknownBase {
    IUnknown* myEl;
public:
    UnknownBase(IUnknown* el) { myEl = el; }
    ...
};

public class NativeType {
    COMType* myEl;
public:
    Object^ getSomeItem() { 
        IUnknown* el; myEl->getItemNative(&el); return UnknownBase(el); 
    }
};
```

Now, there are a number of those "AnotherItem" types (first code section above) in the interface, and I was thinking of creating managed + unmanaged wrappers derived from UnknownBase, etc. Then what? How'll I have a corresponding code for C# "as" operator? From MSDN I understand dynamic_cast is the corresponding operator that'll be called for "as", but having wrapped the IUnknown pointer, I cannot depend on dynamic_cast alone. I just tried to find if type cast operators of classes would be used by dynamic_cast (so that I could manually check the type equality in separate type cast operators), but I think it's not?

I have a huge code base on C# side that uses a marshalled + tlbimp'ed interface so I'm trying to keep the interface exactly same (to replace the "from-the-dark-side&buggy"-marshalled interface), hence I came up with dual-wrappers (and actually, separate namespaces, etc to do more magic).

Comment: You got into this pickle because of too many wrappers.  COMType is already a perfectly good type, you made it useless by wrapping it in a typeless class.  You can wrap it yet again by adding more wrappers, now having to duplicate COMType the right way.  But removing wrappers is the much better way ahead.  At the very minimum kill off UnknownBase   And consider whether this is useful at all, C# can already use COMType without any help.

Comment: I'm afraid COMType is from an idl/header, C# cannot see it.

Comment: A primary use for IDL is to generate a type library that you can Tlbimp.  Sure, you can generate a .h as well.  Run midl.exe with /tlb option to ensure it really is a dead avenue, it might be.  Kill off UnknownBase, at least the .h file gives you a known base.

Comment: But the whole reason to using C++/CLI to design a wrapper here (and this question) is to NOT use what you described. I already have an interop dll from tlbimp and based my C# code on that useless venue. There were problems, and now I'm writing my own wrapper - doing everything myself that tlbimp / interop.dll or a p/invoke would do for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I needed to find out what that IUnknown type is, and gcnew a corresponding managed type for it (a ref class). I simplified code for the question above, but normally it's more like the code below (with int id's referring to the correct type). And having an error in the example code above may have made it difficult to answer the question, my apologies.

And also, there's no such thing as conversion between an unmanaged class and object^, so trying to create an UnknownBase(el) wouldn't work.

```
public class NativeType {
    COMType* myEl;
public:
    Object^ getSomeItem(int id) { 
        IUnknown* el; 
        myEl->getItemNative(id, &el); 
        switch(id) {
            case 1: return gcnew AnotherItem(el);
            case 2: return gcnew ... 
        }
    }
};
```

I'll test this soon.